# SQL - How do I create a view that pivots and existing table

Tags: sql, database, pivot, create-view

I have a Table for Our Dynamic fields on user created Forms:

The Table is Formatted like this:

```
ID  | FIELD NAME 
-------------------
1   | Gross Gallons
```

In order to form Joins with other tables I need to create a view that looks like this

```
ID_1 
------------
Gross Gallons
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple approach to make dynamic fields.

Given table:

```
mysql> select * from dyna_field;

+------+---------------+
| id   | field_name    |
+------+---------------+
|    1 | Gross Gallons |
|    2 | Net Gallons   |
|    3 | Total         |
+------+---------------+
```

Make dynamic query:

```
select 
  group_concat(concat('(case when id = ', id, ' then field_name else "" end) as ID_', id, ' ')) into @sql_case
from dyna_field 
join(SELECT @sql_case:='') c;

set @sql_case = concat('select ', @sql_case, ', 1 as uid from dyna_field;');

prepare statement FROM @sql;

execute statement;

+---------------+-------------+-------+-----+
| ID_1          | ID_2        | ID_3  | uid |
+---------------+-------------+-------+-----+
| Gross Gallons |             |       |   1 |
|               | Net Gallons |       |   1 |
|               |             | Total |   1 |
+---------------+-------------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks, this suggestion actually answers my question as it was asked and for that, I apologize. My Table though has Several ID's and FIeld names. IE., ID 2 Is net Barrels....I need that to appear as ID_2 Net Barrels.

Comment: @Dquakenbush You mean, that to have ID_2 as a column in the view?

Comment: Yes, ID_2,ID_3.....ID_286. So I need the ID's to be columns with the Field names as Rows.  Right now both are columns.

Comment: @Dquakenbush I just made it dynamic. You can further improve it to fulfil your need.

Comment: I dont have MYSQL, im working off of SQL Server 2008 R2. It does not have a Group_concat equivalency. Any thoughts on how I can make this work within 2008?

Comment: This was my first question ever on Stackexchange and clearly I have some learning to do in terms of asking the right questions.....I am going to resubmit this question and hopefully I get it right this time

Comment: @Dquakenbush this my help to you if you looking for something similar with SQL Server
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/

Comment: Thank you so much...Very helpful